# Viewing database of an app stored/installed on the device in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Any tool available which can help view the sqlite database stored on the device for a particular app.
Currently am using:

1. Sqlite browser
2. Questoid sqlite manager plug in for eclipse

Both of these work for emulators. in case of sqlite browser i have to pull the database to view it. Questoid is a little better as it allows direct viewing but still through the emulator only.

Any option in which I can see the current state of the database stored on the device preferably without rooting the device.

Comment: Generally, In phone, you cant do it unless it is rooted. If app is debbugable then you have chance to get the db using adb commands

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public void writeToSDCard() throws IOException {


        //  System.out.println("Write To Sd");
        File f=new File("/data/data/com.YourPackageName/databases/YourDBName");
        FileInputStream fis=null;
        FileOutputStream fos=null;

        try{
            fis=new FileInputStream(f);


            fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/dumped.db");
            while(true){
                int i=fis.read();
                if(i!=-1){
                    fos.write(i);
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            fos.flush();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        finally{
            try{
                fos.close();
                fis.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println(ioe);
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code will create a copy of your DB -- from your device and apps internal folder onto the SD Card -- this DB file will be named as dumped.db

#### Make sure you change the package name to your package name and the database name also.

You can place a call to the function WriteToSDCard(); from anywhere in your code and get a dynamic copy of your DB, so that you can check the state.

Once you get the DB file (dumped.db) on your SDCard -- you can easily view it through SQLite browser

#### Cheers  No Root Required!